# Subspace proof $\{\,f \colon\Bbb R \to\Bbb R \mid f(x + 1) = f(x) + 1\,\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have no idea how to show that this is a subspace. Isn't $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=3x$ a counter-example? It is not closed under scalar multiplication? But I guess it is.. $[e]$ forgot to say that the solutions say that it *is* a subspace.

Determine whether $W$ is a subspace of the real vector space $V$, giving proofs or
counterexamples.

$F(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$ denotes the real vector space of all functions $f \colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

$V = F(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)\qquad W = \{\,f\colon \Bbb R \to\Bbb R \mid f(x + 1) = f(x) + 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x \in\Bbb R\,\}$

Comment: It's indeed not a vector space for the argument you said (it's also not closed for the addition).

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yet another reason: the zero function isn't in $W$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote this space by $A$. If $f\in A$ then the function $g(x):=f(x)-x$ satisfies
$$g(x+1)=f(x+1)-(x+1)=f(x)-x=g(x)\ ;$$
hence $g$ is periodic with period $1$. Conversely: If $g$ is periodic with period $1$ then $f(x):=g(x)+x$ is in $A$.

The periodic functions of period $1$ obviously form a subspace $P$ of the vector space $X:={\mathbb R}^{\mathbb R}$. The set $A$ is a translated copy of $P$:
$$A=P+{\rm id}\ ,$$
whereby ${\rm id}\in X$. It follows that $A$ is an *affine subspace* of $X$.